# .Net LuaInterface Hook system / Events

Tags: .net, luainterface

Wondering if it where posible to create a hooking system in .Net with LuaInterface
This system would be like Garry's Mod

```
Hook.Add("HookName", "CustomName", Function()
    print("Called every time HookName is called) 
end
```

I am dead in my tracks with trying to figure out how this would work...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy to do, had this same problem myself, you just need this setup

```
Dim luascript As New Lua()
luascript.RegisterFunction("Print", Me, Me.GetType().GetMethod("Print"))
luascript.DoString("Print('Hello World')")
```

Which will invoke a method called Print, referenced by GetMethod. The Lua and .NET method names do not have to be the same.

```
Public Sub Print(text)
    YourAwesomeListBox.Add(text)
End Sub
```